# How to update field in CSV_1 with values from CSV_2?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two CSV files, table1 and table2, and I am trying to find a way to update the **Price** field in table1 with price values from table2 if-and-only-if table1 and table2 share the same value in the **Name** field.

My two tables look like this:

```
Table 1:

   Price  Name   ATT1  ATT2
0     12   APPL    69    81
1    900  GOOGL   303   392
2     32    INV    39     9

Table 2:

   Price     Name 
0   1231      APPL
1     39  FACEBOOK
```

Successfully performing this join/merge/update would see:

- APPL's price changed to `1231` (from table2)
- GOOGL and INV unchanged (no matching names from table2)
- FACEBOOK left out (no matching name from table1)

```
Expected Final Table:

   Name   ATT1  ATT2   Price
0   APPL    69    81  1231.0
1  GOOGL   303   392     900
2    INV    39     9     32
```

Current code:

```
table1 = pd.read_csv('path/table1.csv', index_col=0)
table2 = pd.read_csv('path/table2.csv', index_col=0)
print(table1)
print(table2)

new_table = table1[["Name ", "ATT1", "ATT2"]].merge(table2[["Price", "Name "]], on="Name ", how="left")
print(new_table)
```

leads to the following, GOOGL and INV being nullified:

```
Current Final Table:

   Name   ATT1  ATT2   Price
0   APPL    69    81  1231.0
1  GOOGL   303   392     NaN
2    INV    39     9     NaN
```

Comment: Can you please give the sample data that we can put into a code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give sample data, I had to hard code it and it was a pain, but I believe this is what you want.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

table1 = [
    ['Price', 'Name', 'ATT1', 'ATT2'],
    [12, 'APPL', 69, 81],
    [900, 'GOOGL', 303, 392],
    [32, 'INV', 39, 9]
]

table2 = [
    ['Price', 'Name'],
    [1231, 'APPL'],
    [39, 'FACEBOOK']
]

column_names_1 = table1.pop(0)
column_names_2 = table2.pop(0)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(table1, columns=column_names_1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(table2, columns=column_names_2)

merged_df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='Name')
merged_df['Price'] = merged_df['Price_y'].fillna(merged_df['Price_x']).astype(int)
final_df = merged_df.drop(['Price_x', 'Price_y'], axis=1)
final_df
```

Output:

```
    Name    ATT1    ATT2    Price
0   APPL    69      81      1231
1   GOOGL   303     392     900
2   INV     39      9       32
```

Comment: I have copied your code directly, ie not reading data from my csv files and i get this output: `  Price_x   Name  ATT1  ATT2  Price_y  Price
0       12   APPL    69    81   1231.0   1231
1      900  GOOGL   303   392      NaN    900
2       32    INV    39     9      NaN     32 `

Comment: Change the last line to a variable. If you display it you will have my output. I'll change my code accordingly and try that instead. Furthermore, trying to say what your output is over the comments isn't very helpful or insightful. Try changing this next time.

Comment: yes that works now, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do this without Pandas:

**table1.csv**

```
Price,Name,ATT1,ATT2
12,APPL,69,81
900,GOOGL,303,392
32,INV,39,9
```

**table2.csv**

```
Price,Name
1231,APPL
39,FACEBOOK
```

My code:

```py
import csv

# Start w/T2, since T1 is the basis for FINAL

# Create a small dict of {t2_name: t2_price, ...}
t2_data = {}

with open('table2.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # discard header

    for row in reader:
        t2_price = row[0]
        t2_name = row[1]
        t2_data[t2_name] = t2_price

# Build FINAL by finding matching names between T1 and T2, and then overwriting price

final_rows = []

with open('table1.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    final_rows.append(next(reader))    # set final header

    for row in reader:
        t1_price = row[0]
        t1_name  = row[1]
        if t1_name in t2_data:         # find shared names
            t2_price = t2_data[t1_name]
            t1_price = t2_price        # overwrite
            row[0]   = t1_price        # ...

        final_rows.append(row)

# Write FINAL

with open('final.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(final_rows)
```

gives me this **final.csv**:

```
Price,Name,ATT1,ATT2
1231,APPL,69,81
900,GOOGL,303,392
32,INV,39,9
```